# Generating script for multiple Contexts, with database reference, in Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core-3.1

I have been able to successfully create multiple DBContexts within my ASP.NET Core application that connect to multiple tables in multiple databases.

After creating my first migrations for both contexts, I'm able to generate my SQL scripts using the command:

```
Script-Migration -Context CustomContext1
Script-Migration -Context CustomContext2
```

When I looked at the result of the script generation, I noticed that both scripts for both contexts don't reference the database of either CustomContext1 or CustomContext2. I'm supposed to send this script down an automated pipeline, which means that the specif DB for each script needs to be included.

How do I get this to happen automatically using the script generation command?

Comment: have you tried with CLI `dotnet ef migrations script  --Context <CONTEXT>`

Comment: Still the same. It generates the script but it doesn't specify the database the script should be executed in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so many days of research and testing, the only way to accomplish this is to manually add the "USE Database" line to the beginning of the generated SQL script.

It makes no sense, really. With the presence of multiple DbContexts, the logical thing to do when SQL scripts are being generated would be to automatically add the "USE Database" line at the beginning of each script.

Perhaps a fix will be included in the next version of EF Core tools. Who knows.